# Own Implementation of Hash

Tags: java, security, hash, hashmap

I am attempting to learn more about password hashing. I am pretty used to java and am trying to write my own hashing function for a password. I understand you should never implement your own password security this is purely an academic endeavor. I have made my own implementation of HashMap and other data structures. I would appreciate a description of how hashing works and code fragments if needed. I have searched for an answer but all I can find is how to use SHA 256 (or others ) to hash a password. I would like to make my own to learn more about the algorithms. Thank you for any and all help.

p.s.
To clarify, I know there are algorithms that you can import in java to hash password. I am looking for a description of how these functions work and how the are similar to a hashMap so I can attempt to replicate it.

Comment: This is way too broad. Requesting code samples and a tutorial on a topic like hashing is far too much. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: I understand this is a broad questions and am not trying to be difficult. Just a description of how hasing a password is different from hashing data into a map. I am not looking for anything specifically just any information that can help with my project.

Comment: @HoldenDinerman I believe the term you're looking for is Cryptographic Hashing. I don't think this question is can be made ontopic though. It seems inherently too broad.

Comment: I just actually searched for that term, and apparently not all Cryptographic Hashing algorithms can actually be securely used for cryptography, but it would be a starting point.

Comment: Thank you I will attempt to start there.

Comment: This is really more of a math question than a programming question. Its about coming up with a mathmatical function which generates hashes that are distributed and unique.

Comment: please note the hashmap is basically a map (a key-value map) and has nothing to do with cryptographic hash.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question but hopefully a few high level details will help you.

Firstly though, as you said, you should not generally implement a secure hashing function yourself since it is very easy to make mistakes resulting in security vulnerabilities.

Cryptographic hashing, such as is provided in SHA-2 at various bit strengths, is a one way cryptographic process of converting your input bytes into an output of the specified length.  Assuming correct algorithms, this output cannot be directly converted back to the input.

For discussions on the SHA-2 algorithm in specific you can start with the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

For designing your own algorithm you would want to take into account the following considerations (as SHA-2 and other hashing algorithms do, excerpted from Wikipedia):

- it is deterministic so the same message always results in the same hash
- it is quick to compute the hash value for any given message
- it is infeasible to generate a message from its hash value except by trying all possible messages
- a small change to a message should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old hash value
- it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash value

Further, for password hashing in particular:

- Going against the "quick" consideration above, password hashing algorithms are generally chosen to be slower and more difficult to implement in hardware (e.g. scrypt) in order to reduce the ability to brute force a password when its hash and salt are known.  Commonly this is done by doing some 1000+ rounds of SHA-2.

Lastly, outside of the hashing algorithm itself, it is important to make sure the password hashes are salted.  Salt here refers to modifying the password (e.g. by prefixing it) before hashing with a randomly generated salt value that is also stored with the hash.  This prevents an existing or single dictionary of password hashes from being used against all hashes in your database were it to be compromised (i.e. it forces an attacker to attack each hash individually).